# how to track or log C# to sql code

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

For Example. I made dbinitializer code like in contosouniversity but mine. 
but nothing appears. I mean table is empty. I can add variables by scaffolded method. It works fine. But DBinitializer now work. how can I track it? 
When I add project by entity nothing appeas. How can I track it? I can`t see error output. Where? Or log SQL.

```
namespace Proj_s.Data
{
    public class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options) : base(options)
        {


        }

public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Worker> Workers{ get; set; }
       // public DbSet<ProjAssignment> ProjAssignments{ get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>().ToTable("Worker");
           // modelBuilder.Entity<ProjAssignment>().ToTable("ProjAssignment");
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: You also need something like `context.Projects.Add(Projects);` `context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Thanks. I commented it cause I have to disable project table. I would try. There would be another question om many to many relationship.

Comment: Please specify Entity Framework version

Comment: I have  
            foreach (Project s in Projects)
            {
                context.Projects.Add(s);
            }
            context.SaveChanges(); but it not work

Comment: look at this..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I would try. I remade my db and it work. but nothing in output when I try ro do wrong. I ask this cause there were output on another machine.

Comment: How can I add it to 
namespace Proj_s.Data
{
    public class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectContext> options) : base(options)
        {
           

        }
      
public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().ToTable("Project");
           // modelBuilder.Entity<ProjAssignment>().ToTable("ProjAssignment");
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

in the constructor of your DbContext class add this.

```
Database.Log = (s) =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        };
```

Comment: Database facade does not contain definition for Log